# Relationship between the solutions of a 2nd Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y_1,y_2$ form a foundamental set of solutions of the 2nd order linear and homogenous ODE:
> $$
> \ddot y+ \cos(x)\dot y+\frac{\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)}{4}y=0\quad(*)
> $$
> Show that $y_2(x)=x\cdot y_1(x),\forall x\in \mathbb R.$

My attempt goes like this: Let  $y_1\neq0$ be a solution of $(*)$ meaning that
$$
\ddot y_1+\cos(x)\dot y_1+\frac{\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)}{4}y_1=0
$$
and
$u(x)=x\cdot y_1(x) ,\forall x\in \mathbb R.$
Then
$$
\ddot u+\cos(x)\dot u+\frac{\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)}{4}u=x\{\ddot y_1+\cos(x)\dot y_1+\frac{\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)}{4}y_1\}+2\dot y_1+\cos(x)y_1=2\dot y_1+\cos(x)y_1.$$

I am stacked here at this point. I have tried using Abel's Type for the Wronskian of $y_1,y_2$: $W[y_1,y_2](x)=Ce^{-\int \cos(x)dx}=Ce^{-\sin(x)}$ but I cannot show that $2\dot y_1+\cos(x)y_1=0$.

Any suggestions?

A correction made driven by the observation of **Gyu Eun Lee**

**Show that there exist solutions $y_1,y_2$ such that $y_2(x)=x\cdot y_1(x),\forall x\in \mathbb R.$**

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are missing an assumption, as the claim is false. If $y_1$ and $y_2$ form a fundamental set of solutions, then so does $y_1$ and $y_2 + Cy_1$ for any constant $C$. So it is impossible to conclude that $y_2 = xy_1$ from the conclusions given here: $y_2 = (x+1)y_1$ would be an equally valid conclusion.

Comment: You are right.I reformed the question properly